# Queue web API requests

Tags: architecture, asp.net-web-api

I have the need to write an application that takes requests from a website to either retrieve information such as the details of a sales account or to post sales invoices to an accounts system.  We will be linking to a number of accounts systems and each has their own toolkit / API or might be file based

The website may be in the DMZ and the accounts system will almost certainly be part of the domain and behind a firewall

Because of the way the toolkits work, one toolkit object can only process one request at a time.  I’ve put a proof of concept together that is basically a self-host web API (for now in a console application but to be a Windows Service) that is processing the requests for specific areas such as codes; sales accounts and sales invoices (more to be added in the real API).  Each of these areas uses its own accounts toolkit object to perform the specific task.  What I have done and this is the bit that I know isn’t right but I don’t know how to do correctly.  Because only one request can be processed at a time I am locking a static object, processing the request and not processing the next request until the previous one has unlocked the static object.

The code in my controller looks like this:

```
public class SalesInvoiceController : ApiController
{
    private static object lockObject = new Object();

    [ActionName("Save")]
    public int Post(SalesInvoice salesInvoice)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                TheRouters.TheSalesInvoiceRouter.PostSalesInvoice(salesInvoice);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: remove as just for debugging
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

But what I would like to know is how I should really be doing the lock bit or is there a more specific way I should be queuing up the web API calls?

Any advice will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well I would attack this problem a lil different. If you need a queueing mechanism, you might consider using a dedicated queue service, such as msmq, rabbitmq, activemq. Their clients are usually tread safe and pooled, at least you can have an instance of client per request.

Otherwise, if you need to do this, you should consider using [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) and try to avoid locking.

Comment: There are a couple of the toolkits that only allow one process at a time, such as a file based system where it needs to write to a file hence only processing one request at a time.

Comment: I did have a look at MSMQ but could not workout how the client would make a request to get the details of a sales accounts, this was queued and then the bit I couldn't work out, send the sales account details to the client

Comment: I dont know anything about your business rules, but i would imagine, you need to process them and sync them to somewhere such as db. once the data is picked from queue and processed on subsequent requests you can read from database. Look at producer/consumer paradigm and add a database to it.

Comment: ps: forget about processing 1 at a time. and locking is not really recommend if you dont have to .

Comment: If I forget about processing 1 at a time how would I handle writing to a file for more than one request at a time?

Comment: why dont u use a database? better than working with files. right?

Comment: Can't use a database as some of the accounts systems we link to only import files.  We don't own the accounts system and therefore can't change them